# Display image on facebook comment without displaying URL?

Tags: php, html, image, .htaccess

I have installed firefox addons from www.webmemes.org, after that

if I pass this text **webmemes.org(aww)** on Facebook comment. i'm getting image without showing real path of the image. How do they do it?

if I try to accessed in Firefox URL tab directly, i'm getting like this image.

[image]

Can any one help me, how this image displaying???..

Comment: If I visit [webmemes.org(aww)](http://webmemes.org(aww)), I get [a normal 404 page](http://i.imgur.com/Qh63gVD.png)... Do you have any extensions running with your browser?

Comment: try to access in firefox you will get, in chrome can't access it

Comment: That's a screenshot of me trying to access it in Firefox... (notice the text "Firefox can't find the server...") Trying to visit that page in chrome redirects me to a search for "http://webmemes.org(aww)/".

Comment: Really sorry i have installed firefox addons www.webmemes.org from this, Even though how it converting and displaying??

Comment: @Nightfirecat i have dissabled addons and checked, image not displaying i got only text...

Answer (score 1):

When using the [Webmemes addon](http://webmemes.org/), text such as `webmemes.org(allthe)` is replaced with a base64-encoded image, like shown below:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN....
```

It almost certainly operates by parsing the document for text that reads `webmemes.org(<memename>)` and replaces it with a data URI image, since that's what the addon does when you opt to add it to any page via a textbox.

Comment: +1 thanks for analyzing.. still i not found solution. if i disabled that plugin image won't display instead webmemes.org(aww) raw text displaying..

Comment: What, then, *are* you asking? I'm not clear on what your question is, if it's not "How is this image getting onto the page?"

Comment: i have tried, 1.http://tysoco.com/temp/ had complete image tag, and 2.http://tysoco.com/temp/base64-image.php had base64 image. but this two path does not displaying image on facebook

Comment: @K6t The image will only show up when you post that text if you have the addon enabled. Anyone who doesn't use that addon will see the plain text instead.